# Use space-delimited string as argument list

Tags: bash

I have a string that contains something like this:

```
apple orange pear grapes
```

And I have a command that works like this:

```
eat food [additionalFood [additionalFood [additionalFood...]]
```

If I do `eat $s`, then it will treat the whole string as one big food. How can I break up the string into passable arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't treat that as one big string.  Example:

**test.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash
for stuff; do
    echo "XXX: $stuff"
done
```

**Command-line**

```
chmod +x test.sh
s="apple orange pear grapes"
./test.sh $s
```

**Output**

```
XXX: apple
XXX: orange
XXX: pear
XXX: grapes
```

If this isn't working for you, it's possible your [`IFS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) variable is set to a non-default value.

Answer (score 1):

If `eat` is not your direct script, use `set`. try `help set` in your terminal

> `set`: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
>       Set or unset values of shell options and positional parameters.

example:

```
$ allargs="foo bar baz"
$ set -- $allargs  # notice no quoting here
$ echo "$1"  # foo
$ echo "$2"  # bar
$ echo "$3"  # baz
```

---

If `eat` is the direct script, then `$1` `$2` are alread set for you, unless your arguments are quoted

```
$ eat foo bar baz 
## then "$1" is foo, "$2" is bar etc
$ eat "foo bar baz"  # quoted arguments
## then "$1" is "foo bar baz"
```

---

More options would include a `for` loop, see @Oli Charlesworth answer,
or even an array:

```
$ arr=($allargs)    # allargs as defined above, also no quoting 
$ echo "${arr[0]}"  # foo
$ echo "${arr[1]}"  # bar
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `for` construction and `awk` for this.